# Best way to filter a relationship from a twig template

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm, twig, relationship

in my Symfony2 project, I've two entities: Spot and Weather, with a one-to-many relationship "weatherReports" between the two entities.

Some weather reports are outdated, so I would like do create an "activeWeatherRecords" method to filter the Weather entities in a Spot entity.

Unfortunately, I can't see how to do this. The idea is not to fetch objects from the controller since the Spot objects are favorited, linked to an User object and accessed directly from a twig template.

So here is the question: What's the best way to filter a relationship directly from a twig template?

**UPDATE 09/11/2013**

I managed to filter my relationship with a filtering method on my relationship.

In my spot entity, I declared a getActiveWeatherRecords() method:

```
public function getActiveWeatherReports()
    {
        // Date
        $date = new \DateTime(date('Y-m-d 12:00:00', time()));

        // Criteria
        $criteria = Criteria::create()
            ->where(Criteria::expr()->gte("date", $date))
            ->orderBy(array("date" => Criteria::ASC))
        ;

        return $this->weatherReports->matching($criteria);
    }
```

And I can call this method from a twig template as simply as follow:

```
[...]
{% for weatherReport in spot.activeWeatherReports %}
[...]
{% endfor %}
[...]
```

Comment: Why don't you just remove outdated reports? You could create simple garbage collector command and run it on schedule. In that command remove reports that are older than X amount of days.

Comment: I would like to keep these reports and use them for statistics, can't really remove them.

Comment: Does your report entity has date? You can compare dates in twig - http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/functions/date.html. You can use it to only show recent reports

Comment: The report entity does have a date, but there will be thousands of them so I can't loop on each to know which one is recent or not.

Comment: How do you select reports to display?

Comment: For now, I don't. I would like to create this "activeWeatherRecords" method to find reports with a date > today at midnight.

Comment: then in "activeWeatherRecords" method in your query add 'where report.date < today.midnight'. This way only recent reports will be pulled from database.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/37136/discussion-between-cyril-and-dmnptr)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way is to create a finder method that fetches only active records. You could put that method in a Doctrine repository, call it from your controller (or the [Service Layer](http://martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/serviceLayer.html)) and pass it to your template.

Another way is to add a [filtering method](https://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.org/en/latest/reference/working-with-associations.html#filtering-collections) right to your entity. This way you don't have to call a separate method and pass the result to a template — the entity you pass to the entity will be enough.

Comment: I think that adding a filtering criteria to my collection is the thing I was looking for, did you ever use it? Where can I find an example of how to integrate it properly in my Symfony2 entity/repository?

Comment: I managed to do what I wanted to do with a filtering method on my relationship. See update in my question.